# Capture stdout in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdout

I've got a function I need to call from a third-party library which I can't control. That function evaluates a command I pass in and prints its results to `stdout`. In my use case, I need to capture the results into a std::string variable (not write to a file), which I can do just fine in a single-threaded example:

```
int fd[2];
pid_t pid;

char *args[] = {};
if ( pid == 0 )
{
    dup2( fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO );
    close( fd[0] );
    close( fd[1] );

    char *args[] = {};

    // This func will print the results I want to stdout, but I have no control over its code.
    festival_eval_command("(print utt2)");

    execv( args[0], args );
}

close( fd[1] );
char buffer[1000000];
ssize_t length = read( fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1 );
std::string RESULT = buffer;
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer); // clear the buffer

// RESULT now holds the contents that would have been printed out in third_party_eval().
```

Some constraints/detail:

- My program is multi-threaded, so other threads may be using `stdout` simultaneously (my understanding is that C++ ties the output from multiple threads into `stdout`)
- The third-party library is [Festival](https://github.com/festvox/festival), an open-source speech synthesis library written in LISP (which I have no experience in). I'm using its C++ API by calling: `festival_eval_command("(print utt2)");`
- `festival_eval_command` appears to use `stdout`, not `std::cout` (I've tested by redirecting both in a single-threaded program and only the `stdout` redirection captures the output from `utt2`)
- As far as I can tell from the source, `festival_eval_command` doesn't allow for an alternate file descriptor.
- This function is only being run in one of the threads of my multithreaded program, so I'm only concerned about isolating the `festival_eval_command` output from the other threads' `stdout`.

My question: **Is there a way I can safely retrieve the just results of `festival_eval_command()` from stdout in a multi-threaded program?** It sounds like my options are:

- Launch this function in a separate process, which has its own `stdout`. Do the IO redirection in that separate process, get the output I need and return it back to my main program process. Is this correct? How would I go about doing this?
- Use a mutex around the `festival_eval_command`. I don't quite understand how mutexes interact with other threads though. If I have this example:

```
void do_stuff_simultaneously() {
    std::cout << "Printing output to terminal..." << std::endl;
}

// main thread
void do_stuff() {
    // launch a separate thread that may print to stdout
    std::thread t(do_stuff_simultaneously);

    // lock stdout somehow

    // redirect stdout to string variable
    festival_eval_command("(print utt2)");

    // unlock stdout
}
```

Does the locking of stdout prevent `do_stuff_simultaneously` from accessing it? Is there a way to make stdout thread-safe like this?

Comment: From a brief test, it seems you can already lock std::cout, with `std::cout.rdbuf()->_Lock();`, if you call that before `third_party_eval()` and then call `std::cout.rdbuf()->_Unlock();` when you want other threads to be able to write to it that might work?

Comment: You will need to implement locking so only one of your execution threads can call the third party library, at a time. Before calling it, lock the mutex, unlock it when the function returns. Now, you can be sure that the output you captured came from a single execution thread. Sounds simple, right?

Comment: Please don't add multiple "EDIT:" sections! Previous revisions are available anyway and you should aim at making it one coherent question, not multiple pieces.

Comment: Thanks @ColonD. It looks like since the output is going to `stdout` and not `std::cout`, that implementation might not work. I'm a little fuzzy on stdout vs std::cout though, even after googling around and reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt. I've incorporated the edits into the body of the question. Hopefully it's clear.

Comment: Festival already has a server component (assuming that fork? didn't change that). The C library you're using is not mandatory for communication with it. The docs even have http://festvox.org/docs/manual-2.4.0/festival_28.html#Server_002fclient-API which would be easy to implement.

Comment: I did not know stdout and std::cout are different but that makes sense because std::clog and std::cerr also output to the console (presumably also stdout)

Answer (score 0):

> However, my program is multi-threaded, so other threads may be using `stdout` simultaneously

The outputs of threads are going to be interleaved in a fashion you cannot control. Unless each thread writes its entire output using one `std::cout.write` (see below for why).

> Is there a way I can safely retrieve the just results of `third_party_eval()` from `stdout` in a multi-threaded program?

Each thread must run that function in a separate process, from which you capture its `stdout` into a `std::string s` (different one for each process).

Then in parent process you write that `std::string` into `stdout` with
`std::cout.write(s.data(), s.size())`. `std::cout.write` locks a mutex (to protect itself from data race and corruption when multiple threads write into it in any way, including `operator<<`), so that the output of one process is not interleaved with anything else.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the function in question actually uses `std::cout` but wouldn't be surprised if it used something else.

Answer (score 0):

Note up front: This shows why globals are often a bad idea! Even more, library code (i.e. code intended for re-use in different contexts) should never use globals. This is also something to tell the supplier of that code, they should fix their library to provide a version that at least takes an output filedescriptor instead of writing to `stdout`.

Here's what I would consider doing: Move the whole function execution to a separate process. That way, if multiple threads need to run it, they will start separate processes with separate outputs that they can process independently.

An alternative way is to wrap this single function. This wrapper does all the IO redirection and it (being a critical section) is guarded by a mutex, so that two threads invoking the wrapper will be serialized. However, this has downsides, because in the meantime, that code still messes with your process' standard streams (so a stray call to output something would be mixed into the function output).

A second alternative is to put the function into a wrapper process who's only goal is to serialize the use of the function. You'd start that process on demand or on start of your application and use some form of IPC to communicate with it.